# Android Room FOREIGN KEY constraint failed code 787

Tags: android, android-room, android-database

I have the following tables with one to one relationship between them:
- ServiceLocation
- User
- ServiceLocationAndUser

```
@Entity(tableName = "service_technician",
        foreignKeys = @ForeignKey(entity = UserDb.class,
                                  childColumns = "user_id",
                                  parentColumns = "user_id"
        ))
public class ServiceTechnicianDb {

  @PrimaryKey
  private Integer id;
  private String name;
  private boolean active;
  @ColumnInfo(name = "user_id")
  private Integer userId;
}
```

Here is User table:

```
@Entity(tableName = "user")
public class UserDb {

  @PrimaryKey
  @ColumnInfo(name = "user_id")
  private Integer id;
  @ColumnInfo(name = "first_name")
  private String firstName;
  @ColumnInfo(name = "last_name")
  private String lastName;
}
```

Here is last table:

```
public class ServiceTechnicianAndUser {

  @Embedded private ServiceTechnicianDb serviceTechnician;

  @Relation(parentColumn = "user_id",
            entityColumn = "user_id", entity = UserDb.class)
  private UserDb user;
```

I am trying to insert ServiceTechnician that contains only one user.

```
@Dao public abstract class ServiceTechnicianDao implements BaseDao<ServiceTechnicianDb> {

  @Transaction
  @Query("SELECT * FROM service_technician")
  public  abstract Flowable<List<ServiceTechnicianAndUser>> getAll();
}
```

Here is BaseDao.

```
public interface BaseDao<E> {

  @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
  Single<Long> insert(E e);

  @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
  Single<List<Long>> insert(List<E> list);

  @Update Single<Integer> update(E e);

  @Delete Single<Integer> delete(E e);

}
```

The error:

`android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConstraintException: FOREIGN KEY constraint failed (code 787 SQLITE_CONSTRAINT_FOREIGNKEY)`

What error I am making when linking foreign keys between parent and child tables?

Comment: The error message is about scenario when you're trying to fill the field "userId" in your "service_technician" table with the value that is absent in field "user_id" in your "user" table, isn't it? You haven't show your code with this try-to-insert action, but maybe it's the source of problem, not the Room-settings for foreign keys?

Comment: So, you think that I first should insert `user `object, a then `service_technician` object, since `service_technician` object contains `user` object. After I insert users, then I should be able to inser `servicen_technician` objects since it will have `userId` reference.

Comment: I guess that Room can not do this for me, so I need manually do this?

Comment: Yes, by "Foreign Key" you just put constraint - do not permit to use values other than are in the some field in another table. That's all )

Comment: Is this limitation of SQLite or Room that it can not automatically insert related tables of foreign key?

Comment: I wouldn't say it's limitation. Foreign keys weren't "designed" to implement such a behaviour. They rather about preventing actions that could make  links between tables illegal

Comment: Do I mistake or in other databse systems like MySQL, I would not have to do this manual work? It will save parent but also related tables, am I right?

Comment: I can't be sure on 100%, but my guess that all relational DB's follows the same concept

Comment: Also have a look at my question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76840478/sqliteconstraintexception-foreign-key-constraint-failed-code-787